# Existence of non-constant bounded analytic function on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that there is no non-constant bounded analytic function on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$.

In this homework problem i tried to proceed in the following way: If possible, let $f$ be a non-constant bounded analytic function on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$. Define $F(z)=0$ if $z\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $f(z)$ otherwise. Then $F$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$, i.e., $F$ is entire and also by construction it is bounded. Then by Liouville's theorem $F$ is constant. Which in turn would mean that $f$ is constant. Which is a contradiction.

Am i correct? Can i define such a function $F$? I would be more than happy to get a feedback and if i am incorrect please hint me an idea to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't blindly set $F(z)=0$ at $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and expect $F$ to be analytic, almost always this won't even produce a continuous function.

Comment: Hint: what kind of singularity has $f$ at $0$?

Comment: @DanielFischer The question does not say any thing about the singularities.

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena Thank you.

Comment: It does. Not explicitly, but it does tell you the kind.

Comment: @DanielFischer How can we figure out what kind of singularity does $f$ has at $z=0$. How does that help us to reach to the 'desired' conclusion?

Comment: What kinds of singularities do you know? Which kinds can be excluded by the conditions on $f$?

Comment: @DanielFischer since $f$ is bounded i can exclude the pole at $z=0$.

Comment: Good. So what possibilities remain?

Comment: @DanielFischer Possibilities of Removable and essential singularity are left.

Comment: What do you know about the behaviour of a holomorphic function near an essential singularity?

Comment: @DanielFischer If $z=0$ is an essential singularity of $f(z)$ then in the laurent series expansion of $f(z)$ about $z=0$, the negative powers $z$ continues indefinitely.

Comment: What do you know about the mapping behaviour? Does Casorati-Weierstraß ring a bell?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes thank you alot. Now i got the point.

Comment: If the map is bounded on $\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb Z$, then all integers are removable singularities, and the map extends holomorphically to $\Bbb C$. See the Riemann theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem